# How to Display the messages only once?

Tags: c, arrays

I have 2 struct arrays. i need to check each array of tempo to each array of buff and if a match is found i shall break our of the entire loop and output the message "a match is found" once and exits. Else "no match" should be outputted.

How to Display the messages only once after checking the two arrays with each other? i need to break out of the loop after a match. else output mismatch.
the output is being displayed multiple times.

```
for (int g = 0; g < lines; g++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < lines; y++) {
        if ((strstr(tempo[g], buff[y])) != NULL) //Cheking if enter username and Password Exist in record file.
        {
            printf("A match found on line");
            break;

        } else
        {
            printf("Mismatch in Username or Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy. Do not print it inside the loop. Instead make a note when you do not need it anymore. And only if you do still need it, after the loop, print it. Please provide a [mre] to support making a detailed solution proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable `found` as a flag to indicate when a match is found. You can use test that variable and `break` if it is set to `1`.

Then move the `print` outside the loop and use the flag to determine what to print.

```
int found = 0;
for (int g = 0; g < lines; g++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < lines; y++) {
        if ((strstr(tempo[g], buff[y])) != NULL) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        break;
    }
}

if (found) //Cheking if enter username and Password Exist in record file.
{
    printf("A match found on line");
} else
{
    printf("Mismatch in Username or Password");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with I'm wondering whether you really want to use `strstr` - it searches for a string in another string. That seems a bit strange. Did you mean to use `strcmp`.

I would separate the logic from the print out by writing a function that takes care of the search. The function shall not do any printing.

Something like:

```
int checkForPW(char** tempo, char** buff, int lines)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < lines; g++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < lines; y++) 
        {
            if ((strstr(tempo[g], buff[y])) != NULL)
            {
                // Found - so return 1
                return 1;    
            };
        };
    };
    return 0;
}
```

and call it like

```
if (checkForPW(tempo, buff, lines))
{
    printf("A match found on line");
}
else
{
    printf("Mismatch in Username or Password");
}
```